# QBasicTimer interference with cuda

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, cuda

I had perfomances issues with CUDA in my program. The time taken for the same task (aligning clouds of 3D points) wasn't stable and could be 30 times higher sometimes.

I use Qt for the main interface, which initialize a thread with my worker class. The purpose of this class is to launch cuda computing on my data and to send Qt signals which will be captured by the GUI for updating the display of an OpenGl widget.

I had resolved my performances issues by removing a QBasicTimer in my OpenGL widget, it was used like this :

```
void SWGLCloudWidget::initializeGL()
{
    // ...
    m_oTimer->start(5, this);
}
```

It has no use at all, but i forget to delete it after some refactoring.
In Qt documentation it says :

> The QBasicTimer class provides timer events for objects.
>
> This is a fast, lightweight, and low-level class used by Qt internally. We recommend using the higher-level QTimer class rather than this class if you want to use timers in your >applications. Note that this timer is a repeating timer that will send subsequent timer events >unless the stop() function is called.

I was wondering how this low-level call could cause such a mess with CUDA, just for my curiosity.

Comment: did you overload `void QObject::timerEvent ( QTimerEvent * event )`?

Comment: Yeah, its only contains an updateGl call. So i guess the refresh rate was to hight to allow cuda to take the ownership of the GPU ?

Comment: I made some tests with others values for the timer, under 20ms cuda starts to be unstable. So the gl refresh rate was the problem, thanks !

Comment: np, you are doing most of the work. Which version of Qt is it? what happens if you keep 5 ms but call `update()` instead??

Comment: I have the 4.8 using QGLWidget heritage. It does the same thing, update seems to call updateGL at the same refresh rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I interpret:

As described in the documentation `update()\updateGL()`

> does not cause an immediate repaint; instead it schedules a paint
>   event for processing when Qt returns to the main event loop. This
>   permits Qt to optimize for more speed and less flicker than a call to
>   repaint() does.

If for some reason (other threads, monitor refresh rate limitations,time spent computing new images, other signals and slots,etc...) the screen can be refreshed only every `X` milliseconds and you ask for a refresh rate of `Y > X`, then Qt will keep queuing paint events to the detriment of other events. Thus the system will be even less responsive as you observed.

This is an issue of congestion as it happens in network systems, where the `throughput` (average **successful** rate) is lower and lower than the requested rate.

Comment: If you have Nvidia driver and you run linux, try with the driver enabled\disabled. Wonders may happen :).

Comment: Too bad that i'm using cl with windows seven :p